# Is a CFT quantized on flat space trivial?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

My understanding of CFT (as taught in an introductory class for example) is that we work in Euclidean signature and quantize on a sphere of radius $R$. The spectrum is given by the conformal weights $\Delta$ of the primary operators (via the state-operator mapping) and their descendants via

$$E_n = \frac{\Delta_n}{R}.$$

If we were to instead quantize on a slice of flat space, we would get a trivial spectrum $E_n = 0$ since there is no energy scale. This can also be seen from taking $R\to \infty$ above. So the spectrum on flat space is trivial.

Since, in almost all examples I've encountered, a quantum theory is specified by it's spectrum, is it correct to say that CFT quantized on flat space is trivial? Are there any subtleties?

Edit: There is a misstatement in this question, that the theory on flat space has a trivial spectrum, as per the comment. (The nonexistence of a mass scale only prohibits a gap, not a spectrum altogether.) This is a point I'd like to understand better.

Comment: In infinite flat space, one expects the spectrum to usually be continuous, $E \in [0,\infty)$, not trivial.

Comment: OK. Is it incorrect to take the $R \to \infty$ limit of the radially quantized spectrum?

Comment: Can you recover the flat space spectrum (or density of states) from the radially quantized  spectrum?

Comment: Recall that the $\Delta$'s are the eigenvalues of the dilatation operator, which is the Hamiltonian in radial quantization. But in usual time slices quantization the Hamiltonian becomes $P^0$, which has a different spectrum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take the limit of $\frac{\Delta_n}{R}$ for $R \to \infty$ with fixed $n$ you do get zero, but keep in mind that you also have infinitely many $\Delta_n$. Thus it might be possible (and is in fact true) that by taking the limit $n \to \infty$ at the same time in appropriate way you end up with a nonzero result for infinite $R$. Then you can immediately conclude that the spectrum is $[0, \infty)$, because by scaling symmetry for every state of energy $E$ there is a state of energy $\lambda E$ for any given $\lambda >0$.

Let me give you a simple example: consider the Laplace equation on a circle of length $L$. Its eigenvalues are $\lambda_n(L):= \left( \frac{n}{L} \right)^2$ where $n$ is an integer. For any given $n$ the limit of $\lambda_n(L)$ for $L \to \infty$ is zero. On the other hand, for every finite $L$ the spectrum is not bounded above. It becomes more and more dense in the half-line $[0, \infty)$ as $L$ is increased. In this sense you do recover correct spectrum of the Laplace operator on $\mathbb R$ in the limit $L \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. In the example you gave, if I'm not mistaken, one can find the density of eigenstates for the laplacian on the real line $\rho(E) \propto E^{-1/2}$. Similarly, can one obtain $\rho(E)$ for a CFT in flat space using the $\Delta_n$? Perhaps even in some limit, using the Cardy formula?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but you may be interested in reading about the Luscher formalism, which is concerned with extracting continuum amplitudes from finite volume (even lattice) eigenenergies. Obviously this is related to questions about density of states. This is not restricted to CFT, but rather is a quite general property of quantum field theory.